# Which Ubuntu version to install (12.04 or 13.04)

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have windows 7 installed in my laptop. I have a lenovo G570 series laptop. I would like to install ubuntu. Can anyone tell me which version to install ( 32-bit or 64-bit and 12.04 or 13.04)

Comment: If you have 64-bit Windows or your system is 64-bit capable I would go with 64-bit. 13.04 is only supported to Jan 2014 so you will have to upgrade to 13.10. 12.04 is supported till April 2017. If you want the latest features 13.04, if you don't want to have to upgrade in less than 7 months 12.04

Comment: How about if you tried to install both and try other distro to see which one suit you better. Some spec/mobo are right for some but not all. For me I tried a lot of distro and not all of them working the same way. Choose what you need. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

64 bit should be fine on that, if you have the Intel® Core™ i5-2450M processor as the specs advertised for your machine say (64 bit instruction set). 12.04 is entirely stable and I have no issues with it, I use the gnome desktop with it. I have open questions on 13.04, so I don't necessarily recommend it unless you have hardware that isn't found with earlier releases (Newer machines) My Lenovo R61i runs 12.04, this is my main machine. My Toshiba Tecra runs dual-boot Ubuntu 13.04/Mint 14.1, I use that one to research with answering questions from people I install for, as I install both Ubuntu and Mint for friends, depending on what they want, and help them get started using it...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can install either one.  I recommend that you install 13.04 64Bit.  You can download it [here](http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu-releases//raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso).  Once downloaded you can either create a bootable DVD or a USB flash drive.  To create either on see the [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) website.

Once you create either of the above two options, just get your system to boot either from the DVD or The USB flash drive, and you're good to go.

If you so desire to check things out before actually installing, once you boot from either, just choose Try Ubuntu, and that will let you try it to see if it works with your hardware, and if you like it.